# Unattended Folder synchronization between Vista and Xp

Tags: sync

I want to automate the folder synchronization between Vista and Xp in a home network like \\10.0.0.3\shared_docs and \\10.0.0.2\shared_docs . One is a Vista Home Premium pc and another a XP Home edition. 
I tried using [Synctoy 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en)

But it doesn't allow automatic synchronization like after every 2 mins. Is there another tool ? How can i schedule an automatic synchronization?

Comment: I found a batch way to do it here : http://www.inspectmygadget.com/2007/09/21/how-to-synchronise-two-folders-on-a-single-machine-using-xcopy/ ... but some GUI tool would be great !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XP offers a the ability to use files on another machine even when that machine is turned off called "Offline Files".

- When both machines are on and connected the files
  are always kept in sync.
- When one machine has been turned off,
  and is then turned on (or disconnected and reconnected to your network) the files are
  all re-synced automatically.

I don't know for sure, but I expect Vista has the same functionality.

To set it up,

(Assuming sharing is enabled on your machines)

Define one of the machines folders as "Shared" (Right click "**Sharing**") (Let us call this the local machine)

One the other machine (lets call this the remote machine), set those shared folders to be "Available off line"

- fROM the Remote Machine find the shared folder on the local machine
- right click
- select "Make available off line"

You should be all set. As you get familiar with syncing off line files, you will see some options as to when to sync. The default settings will sync as I have described.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share less than 2GB, have a permanent internet connection, and don't mind some third-party knowing about those files, then maybe [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/) is an option? It will sync as soon as possible after you saved a file.

One advantage: this will even synchronise when one of the computers is not running (and gives you some backup and a limited revision control).

For sharing on a LAN, it even uses "LAN sync" (currently [in beta](http://blog.getdropbox.com/?p=34)):

> LAN sync knows when Dropboxes are on the same network and will automatically exchange files directly between computers instead of downloading them from our servers - this makes sharing large files in an office environment much faster than was previously possible.

Comment: dropbox is an excellent service indeed. +1 for that.